# OnOptionsItemSelected - Pressing one button executes the action of the other

Tags: java, android

I have an `onOptionsItemSelected` method with two buttons that allow me to change the value of a child by clicking either of them.

One button is "complete" and the other is "inprogress".

I click on the complete button it changes the child value properly and then changes the value to "In-progress" without even clicking the "In-progress" button.

I can't find any similar issues to mine, any help would be much appreciated.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.complete:
            Log.d(TAG, "Complete button tapped");
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            final String key = intent.getStringExtra("passKey");

            status.setText(R.string.Complete);

            DatabaseReference ref = database.child(key);
            final DatabaseReference statusRefComplete = ref.child("Status");

            statusRefComplete.setValue("Complete").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(edit_task.this, "Task Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        case R.id.inprogress:
            Log.d(TAG, "In-Progress button tapped");
            Intent intent2 = getIntent();

            final String key2 = intent2.getStringExtra("passKey");

            status.setText(R.string.Inprogress);

            DatabaseReference ref2 = database.child(key2);
            final DatabaseReference statusRefInProgress = ref2.child("Status");

            statusRefInProgress.setValue("In-Progress").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(edit_task.this, "Task In-Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }//if
                }//OnComplete
            });


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You must add the "break" for every switch-case condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `break` for every condition:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ...
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.complete:
            ....
            break; // -> You must add this line.
        case R.id.inprogress:
            ...
            break; // -> You must add this line.
    }
    ...
}
```

If you don't add that, the code will execute the code for `R.id.complete` but it won't stop. It will keep executing and will run the code for `R.id.inprogress`. So, just the the "break" point!

Comment: Of course! I had that in other onOptions methods, rookie mistake! Thanks!